# How can I avoid serving too many files on Karma server

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am using Karma as my unit test runner. Generally speaking, it is awesome, but I am facing some annoying problem.

The website I am developing on is based on a quite large ui library with about 40000 files. All the resource from the library is loaded on use, so I have to set them all as 'served' files on the Karma server. Thus I will frequently meet the EMFILE error, which means I am opening too many files at the same time.

Of course I can modify the open file maximum through `ulimit -n`, but this is not as graceful as I expected, and loading tens of thousands files is really time-consuming. Furthermore, I am going to work on a shared machine which I do not have root auth.

I am currently using another http-server and let Karma server proxy all the lib files to it, but it is only a temporary solution.

So I am wondering if there is any way to avoid including all the library files as 'served'?

Comment: That is a huge number of files. Are you sure you need all of those files to run your tests? If you use Grunt or Gulp you can concatenate files together and then minify them.  That would not only solve your problem, but make the application's load time faster.  Although for 40,000 files the build task would probably take quite a large amount of time.  Could you possibly give a little snippet of your karma configuration file where you include all of these files?  That could give anyone trying to help some insight.

Comment: Originally I used the pattern like `/lib/resources/**/*` or so, it was really stupid and rude. I am trying to reduce the amount of file included, but sometimes I would not prefer the compacted code as I might use karma's autowatch for writing unit tests and I need source code for debugging.